# How to protect reading flash of stm32f10x

Tags: stm32

I am working on a project using STM32F103 and I have finished development of the firmware. I use ST-Link Utility for downloading stuff to the microcontroller. When I activate read out protection on my chip, it stops working. And I need to protect my firmware. What is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a bit more info to the accepted answer:

From [ST32F10XXX docs](http://www.st.com/resource/en/programming_manual/cd00283419.pdf), section **"2.4.1 Read protection"**:

> The read protection is activated by setting the RDP option byte and
> then, by applying a system reset to reload the new RDP option byte.
>
> *Note: If the read protection is set while the debugger is still
> connected through JTAG/SWD, apply a POR (power-on reset) instead of a
> system reset (without debugger connection).*
>
> Once the protection byte
> has been programmed:

- Main Flash memory read access is not allowed
  except for the user code (when booting from main Flash memory itself
  with the debug mode not active).
- Pages 0-3 (for low- and
  medium-density devices), or pages 0-1 (for high-density and
  connectivity line devices) are automatically write-protected. The rest
  of the memory can be programmed by the code executed from the main
  Flash memory (for IAP, constant storage, etc.), but it is protected
  against write/erase (but not against mass erase) in debug mode or when
  booting from the embedded SRAM.
- All features linked to loading code into and executing code from the embedded SRAM
  are still active (JTAG/SWD and boot from embedded SRAM) and this can be used to
  disable the read protection. When the read protection option byte is altered to a
  memory-unprotect value, a mass erase is performed.
- When booting from the embedded SRAM, Flash memory accesses through the code
  and through data read using DMA1 and DMA2 are not allowed.
- Flash memory access through data read using JTAG, SWV (serial wire viewer), SWD
  (serial wire debug), ETM and boundary scan are not allowed

> **Unprotection**

> To disable the read protection from the embedded SRAM:

- Erase the entire option byte area. As a result, the read protection code (RDP) will be
  0xFF. At this stage the read protection is still enabled.
- Program the correct RDP code 0x00A5 to unprotect the memory. This operation first
  forces a Mass Erase of the main Flash memory.
- Reset the device (POR Reset) to reload the option bytes (and the new RDP code) and,
  to disable the read protection.

> 

*Note: The read protection can be disabled using the boot loader (in this case only a System Reset
is necessary to reload the option bytes). For more details refer to AN2606.*

There's also a write protection on the chip, see the doc.

**ADDED:** STM32 readout protection has problems: https://blog.zapb.de/stm32f1-exceptional-failure/ so be aware.

Answer (score 1):

You have to unlock the flash first.  There should be a call in the STM32 StdPeriph library.  My code looks something like this:

```
/* Read protect the flash.  NEVER EVER set this to level 2.  You can't
 * write to the chip ever again after that. */
FLASH_OB_Unlock();
FLASH_OB_RDPConfig( OB_RDP_Level_1 );
if (FLASH_OB_Launch() != FLASH_COMPLETE)
{
    err_printf("Error enabling RDP\n");
}
FLASH_OB_Lock();
```

Comment: Can you give a little more details?
For ex: When you have to call this from user firmware?